# Kafka producer threads keep increasing

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

We are using Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Binder and we are facing a problem with our application that consumes one topic and process the messages then outputs them to different topics.

These topics are also consumed within the same application and output to a final topic.

We noticed a huge number of producers threads being created whenever new messages are consumed by the first consumer and these threads remain live.

Here is my simplified config :

```
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: schedulingConsumer;consumerSearch1;consumerSearch2
      default:
        group: ${kafka.group}
        contentType: application/json
        consumer:
          maxAttempts: 1
          backOffMaxInterval: 30
          retryableExceptions:
            org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: false
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: ${kafka.brokers}
          headerMapperBeanName: kafkaHeaderMapper
          producerProperties:
            linger.ms: 500
            batch.size: ${kafka.batchs.size}
            compression.type: gzip
          consumerProperties:
            session.timeout.ms: ${kafka.session.timeout.ms}
            max.poll.interval.ms: ${kafka.poll.interval}
            max.poll.records: ${kafka.poll.records}
            commit.interval.ms: 500
            allow.auto.create.topics: false
      bindings:
        schedulingConsumer-in-0:
          destination: ${kafka.topics.schedules}
          consumer.concurrency: 5

        search1-out:
          destination: ${kafka.topics.groups.search1}
        search2-out:
          destination: ${kafka.topics.groups.search2}

        consumerSearch1-in-0:
          destination: ${kafka.topics.groups.search1}
        consumerSearch2-in-0:
          destination: ${kafka.topics.groups.search2}

        datasource-out:
          destination: ${kafka.topics.search.output}
```

Here is a screenshot from the threads activity :
[image: Thread activity]

We have tried to separate the first consumer `schedulingConsumer` from others :  `consumerSearch1` and `consumerSearch2` and the problem seems to be resolved.

The problem occurs when we have all these consumers running in the same instance.

Comment: How many partitions does the topic have? You can have one thread per partition for max parallelism.

Comment: If you are not using transactions, there should be only producer per output binding; please provide an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Debugging this by capturing the number of times KafkaProducer's constructors are invoked might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you everyone. It seems like a bug in spring cloud stream. I have reported it here : 
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2452

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like it's a bug in spring cloud stream. I have reported it to the team [Kafka producer threads keep increasing when 'spring.cloud.stream.dynamic-destination-cache-size' is exceeded #2452](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2452)

So, the solution was to override the property `spring.cloud.stream.dynamic-destination-cache-size` and set a value greater the number of your output bindings.

For my case I had 14 output bindings.